# Determining root cause for Renault Clio not starting

Tags: battery, starting, renault

My Renault Clio 1.2L 2002 16v occasionally has issues with starting if I don't drive it for a while (usually prolonged periods). Typically its usually the battery and either jump starting or using a battery charger fixes the issue.

However I went to start my car yesterday, having last drove it last Friday and noticed that it would not start or even turn over. When turning on ignition, it appears that the battery light displays indicating an issue with the battery. Despite this warning light, the radio, lights and other electronics all work OK.

Given this warning light I have tried to both charge the battery, in case it low and I also have tried jump starting it multiple times off different cars, in the hope I could at least get it started.

However neither of these solutions fixed the issue and when I try to start the car nothing happens. There isn't really any sound (bar a quiet hum) and it doesn't turn over as said. I've know other common issues can relate to the start motor locking up and the spade connector from the ignition which I have had previously so have tried common fixes to these issues such as putting the car in gear 2 or 4 and rocking back and forth and also cleaning the metal prong.

I've also run a diagnostics tool for error codes in case there was an issue there, but found new issues either. I do have a p0500 speed sensor error but this was present before the the issue with no starting occurred. None of these helped in getting the car to start. I'm assuming its still probably an issue with the battery, even though the battery is relatively new so am hoping I wont have to purchase another new battery

So in light of this I am wondering what my next steps can be in identifying the issue and any other steps I could try in order to get it running?

Comment: Does the starter turn the engine over when you use jump leads to another car?

Comment: @HandyHowie No it doesn't

Comment: But the dash lights come on?  Do things like the windscreen/windshield wipers, horn and headlights work?

Comment: @HandyHowie Yes light, wipers, horn and headlights all work

Comment: Have you looked at your OBD codes?

Comment: @GdD Yes, only code is p0500 speed sensor fault but I have had this error code for  before this specific issue with the car not starting occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have 2 separate problems, your previous problems with your battery could be due to a power drain or it could be your battery is simply on your way out. The current problem doesn't sound battery related, if it was a bad battery it would start when jumped. It's typical for the battery light to be on before starting your car, you probably didn't notice it before.

As you have no codes I would treat this as a starter issue and troubleshoot accordingly. First check the fuse, then look at the starter relay if that's separate from the starter motor. Check the connections to the starter to make sure they are free from corrosion and tight, then use a multimeter to check that it's getting power and that the relay wire gets power when the key is turned.

When working with the starter do it carefully, there's a lot of energy going there!

Answer (score 1):

Things to try -

Identify the starter relay in the fuse box.  You should be able to identify this either from the manual or the lid of the fuse box.  See if it makes a clicking sound when you try to start the engine.

You could identify another identical relay in the fuse box and swap them over to see if that helps.

Check that the engine earth strap is connected correctly.

On the starter motor, there will be a very thick wire and a thin wire.  The thin wire is the one that controls the starter motor.  Check that the wire is connected and clean.  Check if there is power on it while trying to start the engine.  You could disconnect it from the started and connect it to a bulb to test this.

If there is power to the thin starter wire and the starter solenoid on the starter motor still doesn't make a loud click when you try to start the engine, then there is a good chance that the starter needs repairing/replacing.